# VS Code: Auto-indent on tab press to match indentation of previous line

Tags: tabs, visual-studio-code

For comparison:

In Sublime (and also Atom), if I press tab under a line of code that already has 4 tab spaces, Sublime will automatically jump to the same tab spacing of the previous line (4 tab spaces).

In VS Code – when trying to accomplish the same thing – tabs will *fail* to 'jump' to the previous line's spacing, and force me to manually press tab multiple times, instead of once.

Is there a work-around, or am I missing something?

Sublime, Atom - 1x tab press

[image]

VS Code - 4x tab press

[image]

Comment: Well, maybe don't erase when you go to a new line, so you won't even have to press tab once

Comment: Duly, noted. The difference is still there, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you add this to your settings, you'll be able to just type out the line without watching indentation and whenever you hit enter, vscode will indent that previously written line automatically:

```
"editor.formatOnType": true
```

I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but I thought I might as well share and hope this is a satisfying answer.